# Data Driven Selenium Getting exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.0"

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, data-driven

Below is the code that I am referring for Data driven with excel in selenium. With this code I am getting exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.0"

```
public String[][] getDataFromSheet(String excelfilename,String sheetName) {
    String datasets[][] = null;
    try {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        int totalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        int totalCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        datasets = new String[totalRow - 1][totalCol];

        for (int i = 1; i < totalRow; i++) {

            XSSFRow rows = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < totalCol; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = rows.getCell(j);

                if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                    datasets[i - 1][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                }
                else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    String cellText = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    datasets[i - 1][j] = cellText;
                } else {
                    datasets[i - 1][j] = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                }
            }
        }

        return datasets;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return datasets;
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line do you get this? if you are trying to cast it to an int, that's normal, since int nor Integer allow decimals.

Comment: In your exception handler add `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: but honestly, I don't really see anything in this code that I would expect to throw such an Exception. Are you sure this code is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is coming from this piece of code? Can you provide a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @debugger89; you are correct. The issue is not with the code. This solved by parsing the value to Double.intValue().

Answer (score -1):

test this code for read excel file and set according to your requirnment.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        //Path Of your File Enter here
         InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("/home/chavdaan01/Desktop/Aniruddh.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            XSSFRow row; 
            XSSFCell cell;
            //int break_down=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            int i = 0; 
            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                int j = 1;
                while (cells.hasNext())
                {
                    cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();

                    if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {

                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());


                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());


                    }else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {

                        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());


                }



                }



            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
}

}
```

Comment: you can get sheet 
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(name);

Comment: Do not see any difference other than that you switched the for loop to an iterator.

Comment: why would you recommend someone who can't find the problem to write code like: catch(Exception e) {} ? not only will he still not find it, he won't even be noticed an exception occured.